# AutoHotkey: shift + number mapping

Tags: keyboard, mapping, autohotkey, shift

I'm trying to remap some keys in AutoHotkey. This is the code I'm using in `AutoHotkey.ahk`:

```
+8::Send, {*}
+9::Send, {(}
+0::Send, {)}
```

However, this is not working at all. I keep getting `(` when I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant was: when i type SHIFT + 8, i got "(", but i need the returned character to be an asterisk " * "

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you running it inside some special program? For example, some games block all ahk input. / btw, you can edit your own posts

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the comma, this should work:
`+8::Send {*}
+9::Send {(}
+0::Send {)}`
you can also map like this:
`+8::*
+9::(
+0::)`
Although I couldn't map number keys this way for some reason. finally if all else fails you could try mapping by scan code

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the & to create a custom combination of two keys - see http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Features for an introduction.

```
shift & 8::Send {*}
```

Also note that:

> The **first comma** of any command may be omitted (except when the first parameter is blank or starts with := or =, or the command is alone at the top of a continuation section - see 
>   http://ahkscript.org/docs/Scripts.htm#esc